# Objective C - error - sending double to parameter of incompatible type double

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to objective C and is having trouble passing a double value to a method. Someone please be kind enough to help me.

I've this function

```
- (UIColor *) setColorConstrains:(double *) p1 :(double *) p2 :(double *) p3 :(double *) p4 :(double *) value{
    if (value < p1 || value > p2)
        return [UIColor redColor];
    else if (value < p3 || value > p4)
        return [UIColor orangeColor];
    else
        return [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

And I'm trying to call it like

```
[self setColorConstrains:15.0 :29.9 :18.5 :24.9 :&value];
```

But its giving me error

```
sending double to parameter of incompatible type double
```

Here is the method inside of which I'm calling the first method

```
- (UIColor *) getColorByValue:(NSString *) vitalName :(NSString *) vitalValue
{

    double value = [vitalValue doubleValue];

    if([vitalName isEqualToString:@"BMI"])
        return [self setColorConstrains:15.0 :29.9 :18.5 :24.9 :&value];
}
```

Comment: double, not double*. You don't want to pass a pointer to double. And unless you have a very very very good reason, name your parameters. How am I supposed to know what these weird numbers in the call mean? It's also a good idea to avoid spelling errors in method names. How would I remember that I need to misspell setColorConstraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UIColor *) setColorConstrains:(double ) p1 :(double ) p2 :(double ) p3 :(double ) p4 :(double ) value{
if (value < p1 || value > p2)
    return [UIColor redColor];
else if (value < p3 || value > p4)
    return [UIColor orangeColor];
else
    return [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

You want double,not doublle *

Then call

```
[self setColorConstrains:15.0 :29.9 :18.5 :24.9 :value]
```